# Подскажите что обозначают эти параметры

Tags: python, mysql, pymysql

Подскажите, что значат эти параметры(pool_options=) в коде и какие ставить самые оптимальные.

```
db = ConnectionPooled(host='192.0.0.1', database='foo',
                          pool_options=dict(max_size=10, max_usage=100000, idle=60, ttl=120))
```

Речь идёт об этой библиотеке = https://github.com/zhouyl/pymysql-connection-manager

Спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Это опции для настройки пула подключений к БД. Подробнее можно почитать здесь https://habr.com/ru/post/194142/

Если проект небольшой то пул можно не использовать